# Как добавить запись с помощью функции file_put_contents в JSON файл

Tags: php, json

задача в том,что нужно с помощью ф-ции

```
function writeJSON(){
    $conn = connect();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM goods";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $out = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $out[$row["id"]] = $row;
        }
        $file = 'goods.json';
        $current = file_get_contents($file);
        $current .= json_encode($out);
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "0";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

вытащить из mysql данные и дописать их в уже существующий JSON файл.
Дело в том что функция `file_put_contents` выполняется, как и все предыдущие мои функции для этой задачи, я проверяю их в консоли, поэтому ошибок в коде быть не может, но когда открываю JSON файл никаких изменений не происходит. Делал проверку на доступность для записи с помощью ф-ции `chmod`,она отвечает что файл доступен.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема

Comment: вам все же надо наверное считать файл, раскодировать json, объединить два массива, закодировать, и записать? вы не можете просто взять и присоединить строку к файлу, получите невалидный json

Comment: Да,так более корректно

Comment: Добавляйте сразу в конец файла `file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND)`, без считывания содержимого из файла

Comment: И скорее всего при таком методе добавления данных у вас в файле не будет валидный json.